# how to select multiple same column in one column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables that is  :

1. theatre(id,tname,taddress)
2. movie(id,mname,tid).

In theatre table there is one record with id 1, like :

```
 1, Big Cinema, abc.
```

And in moive table there are 3 record like :

> 1) 1, Race, 1.
>   2) 2, BMB, 1.
>   3) 3, SOTY, 1.

Now I want to show theatre name only one time and with all three movie.

Comment: How do you want them displayed? Also, what are the column names are in the second table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you need ?

```
select [id],[tname],
    stuff((select ',' + CAST(t2.[mname] as varchar(10))
    from movie t2 where t1.[id] = t2.[tid]
    for xml path('')),1,1,'') SomeColumn
from theatre t1
group by [id],[tname]
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/33c24/1)**

Comment: Thanks,

I want to display data like :

Theare name  Movie : 
Big Cinema    Race
              BMB
              SOTY

Comment: @VIPULPARMAR **[Check this Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/33c24/3)** And the SQL Query for the same is **`select [tname] TheatreName,
    stuff((select ',' + CAST(t2.[mname] as varchar(10))
     from movie t2 where t1.[id] = t2.[tid]
     for xml path('')),1,1,'') Movie
from theatre t1
group by [id],[tname]`**

Comment: I want show this movie name in gridview. So it can be possible. Pls reply me.

Comment: I don't have C# code i want to design this. That has one gridview first Headerfield is theatreName, second Headerfield has another datalist and in datalist shows all movie name. So how it is possible pls reply me.! Thanks

Comment: Hi I wan't to design gridview inside another gridview with insert,update, and delete and 
table are 
1) tbl_Show(ShowID{P},ShowTime,Silver,Gold, Platiniam,ShowTimeId)
2) tbl_STime(ShowTimeId{P},TheatreId,MovieId,FromDate,ToDate)
3) tbl_Theatre(TheatreId{P},TName,Taddress)

I wan't to design same like this so visit

www.codeproject.com/Articles/14293/Gridview-Inside-a-GridView-in-ASP-NET-2-0

so please help me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If did you mean to concatinate some columns in one column you can try

```
Select t.tname + ' ' + t.taddress as tNameAdress, m.mname 
from movie m inner join theatre t on m.tid = t.id
```

Comment: Thanks, I want to display data like : Theare name, Movie : Big Cinema, Race, BMB, SOTY